# How to make one check box checked at a time among more than one checkbox in android

Tags: android, checkbox

Friends I need to check only one check-box at a time among more than one check-box.Can any one have the code and idea please.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of CheckBoxes you should use RadioButtons in a RadioGroup.

[image: RadioButtons in a RadioGroup]

Putting the RadioButtons in a RadioGroup ensures that only one of them will ever be selected.

If you don't like the way they look, you can customize them, like you can with any other layout element.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but i want to use Check-Box.

Answer (score 0):

assign id's to your Checkbox and select any checkbox and retreive its id

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ll try and return back to you

Answer (score 0):

android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice use android 's default layout may help u.

Answer (score 0):

For Single Item checked at a time then you have to simply use :-

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice
```

For Multiple Checkbox at a time then you can use this :-

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it and return back to you